Excel Data Connection Causes "your changes could not be saved because of a sharing violation" Error
I have two Excel workbooks, let's call them 'Source.xlsx' and 'Destination.xlsx'. 'Destination' has a simple data connection to 'Source' (Data->Get Data->From File->From Excel Workbook). It looks this version of Excel uses Power Query and I don't see an option for any other type of connection. I am working in both workbooks at the same time. After I refresh the data ('Source' to 'Destination'), I can no longer save any changes in 'Source' because I get the "your changes could not be saved because of a sharing violation" error.
I don't know if this is intended behavior, but it appears that the moment Power Query updates it locks the connected file (at least if it is currently open). Is anyone aware of setting I can change or a workaround to fix this? I'm pretty sure this is new behavior. In previous versions of Excel I worked like this and didn't have this issue.
Version: Office Home and Student 2021 (Excel Version 2407 Build 17830.20138 Click-to-Run)
Update: Also occurs in Office 365 (Excel Version 2404 Build 17531.20190 Click-to-Run)

On a whim I tried something and it worked. Disable background refresh. In my version of Excel this is how I get there:
Data-> Properties (Queries & Connections)
Under Query, next to Name: Click icon with two bullet points
This should bring up the "Query Properties" window. Uncheck 'Enable background refresh'.
